# How to create an association and migration for a 1:many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

I have 2 models:

```
Department
 has_many :accounts

Account
 belongs_to :department
```

But I need to somehow create a table that has:

```
departments_accounts
department_id
account_id
```

This isn't a many-to-many table though is it?  Since a department can have many accounts, but not the other way around.

How should I create a migration that will setup the new table using migrations?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correct, you want to create a [has_many :through](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) (many-to-many) relationship between `Department` and `Account`.

```
rails g model DepartmentAccount department:references account:references
```

This will create a model `DepartmentAccount` with the associations:

```
belongs_to :department
belongs_to :account
```

And you have to change your `Department` model to have

```
has_many :department_accounts
has_many :accounts, through: :department_accounts
```

And the `Account` model needs to have

```
has_many :department_accounts
has_many :departments, through: :department_accounts
```